# Alternative to multiple For Loops and functions being slow

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I need to calculate a combination of different scenarios (indicated as columns of DF1, DF2, and D3) and pass them through a function in 3 for loops below. The function doesn't get an array as input so I have to iterate over the rows to pass the parameters one by one.

However, this is becoming really slow and taking a very long time (index goes to 3000, multiplied by 6*3*3 for i,j,k). 
Is there any way to simplify this? 
Your help will be appreciated since I didn't find an example like that needs to pass through rows and loops.

```
 count=0
  for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    print(index)
    for i in range(0,6):
      for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,3):
          OUT.loc[index,count]=FUNCTION(DF1[index,k],DF2[index,i],DF3[index,j],row[col])
          count += 1
```

Edits

Function is set_tmp taken from here (which doesn't take the column of a dataframe so I have to pass the data row by row): pythermalcomfort https://github.com/CenterForTheBuiltEnvironment/pythermalcomfort/blob/master/examples/calc_set_tmp.py

```
DF1.head(3) 
    Temp    T10p    T90p
1   303.04935   302.04935   304.04935
236 303.57208   302.57208   304.57208
471 301.36523   300.36523   302.36523

DF2.head(3)
    Tmrt_1     Tmrt_2      Tmrt_3      Tmrt_4      Tmrt_5       Tmrt_6
1   25.80   23.52   21.91   25.63   23.51   21.97088
236 25.61   23.38   21.81   25.50   23.42   21.92352
471 24.91   22.76   21.23   24.81   22.78   21.31014

DF3.head(3)
WindSpeed   V10p    V90p
1   2.26    1.134   3.4030
236 1.66    0.831   2.4958
471 1.83    0.915   2.7475
```

Tnx for your help!

Comment: it would help to see FUNCTION, DF1,DF2,DF3, and how OUT suppose to look like? anyway the loop is not too expansive, try to use OUT.at instead of OUT.loc or build a complete row then append it to OUT

Comment: edited the question with additional info. Thanks!

Comment: i tried at instead of iloc as well but it didn't make it that much faster :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

def f(a,b,c,d):
    return int(a+b+c+d)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,6))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,1))
out = pd.DataFrame()
#till here we created the random data frames
start = time.time()
count = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                out.loc[index, count] = f(df1.at[index,k], df2.at[index,i], df3.at[index,j], row[0])
                count+=1
print(time.time()-start)
# for 100 rows time is +- 11 seconds
start1 = time.time()

out1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(list(df1.loc[i])) #add each row as a list to tmp
    tmp.append(list(df2.loc[i]))
    tmp.append(list(df3.loc[i]))
    tmp.append([r[0]])
    all_comb = list(it.product(*tmp)) # create a list of all possible combinations from tmp
    count = 0
    for comb in all_comb:
        out1.loc[i,count] = f(*comb) #send combinations to same function
        count+=1

print(time.time()-start1)
#for 100 rows time is 0.8 seconds

print(len(out))
print(len(out1))
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and I learned a more efficient way of doing loops

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rethink your approach. Sometimes, thinking out of the box results us to a solution with `O(1)` time complexity. If you give your original question, i.e., why you need combination, maybe, then I could help you. Maybe you don't need combination at all.